# PM2 running but socket.io stops responding at times

Tags: mongodb, node.js, socket.io

I am using a hostgator vps with apache, for backend, I am using node.js and socket.io, it works fine but at times it just stops working. Pm2 is showing it online but it just stops responding.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks...

Comment: Sure! You give absolutely no clues, nor your website name, nor your code, nor your specific errors messages...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek there is no error it just doesn't respond, and it's not a website, it's the backend of an application.

Comment: This does not give any more clues. Search in your logfiles.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The only error I am able to log are ios and Android logcats printing "error connecting to socket.io"

Comment: Logfiles at the server end... to see if the query arrived there. If yes, the problem is on the server not replying, if no the problem is on the network or addressing issues from the client.

Comment: Hello, same issue here. Please, how did you solve this?